# One synonym in SSMS isn't showing up in the intellisense. But every other synonym is.

Tags: sql, intellisense, ssms, ssms-2012

In the following image, you can see a small section of our synonym list.

[image: Synonym List]

In the intellisense, I can't see **dbo.SYN_MC_Asset**, but I see the other synonyms. Any ideas on why this is occurring?

[image]

Comment: did you try `Edit` |`Refresh Local Cache` already?

Comment: @LuisLL Just did. The intellisense went away completely for a moment. Then it came back and I still can't see the synonym.